# Use effekt with angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-animation

How use effekt animation with angularjs
http://h5bp.github.io/Effeckt.css/dist/?

Anyone can create a exemple to use this with angularjs?

Comment: might look at `animate.css` in conjunction with `ng-animate`, don't need a js library as supplied in your link

Comment: Can you give a example to implemented with Effeckt?

Comment: If you want modals and such, would need to wrap the js into directives to use in angular, since they are self initializing on page load it seems. Similar issue as using `bootstrap.js` with self initializing `data-` attributes. Frameworks that bind events in this manner don't fit well into angular...since angular creates elements after page load

Comment: you could use the css though in conjunction with `ng-animate` , `'ng-show` etc which is why I suggested googling for `angular animate.css` since it has been around longer and examples , directives, and blog posts exist

Comment: Great post about animations with Angular 1.2, pretty much the best documentation there is right now, from my perspective.
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact,
With effeckt.css in 2 second to create effect, it is very simple and it is beautiful.
Create effect last item created : ng-class="{'new-item': $last}"

example :
Just indicate :

```
<table class="effeckt-list" data-effeckt-type="expand-in">
    <tr ng-repeat="seller in sellers" class="repeat-item" ng-class="{'new-item': $last}" >
        <td>
            <a href="#">{{ seller.name }}</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{seller.typeSeller}}
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

And some some sample data for your controller:

```
$scope.sellers = [
    {
        name : "Lee",
        typeSeller : "Type 1"
    },
    {
        name : "Ella",
        typeSeller : "Type 2"
    },
    {
        name : "Christina",
        typeSeller : "Type 3"
    }
];
```

**[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/markwylde/1f14kb6w/)**

Comment: Nice example. I have added a JSFiddle as a demo. Note you can remove ng-class and just add a `new-item` as a class to make all the items have the effect.